# How to list arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, list

This is my first time creating a program using array lists and I have come to a small problem. A small description of code...you list an employee's info (ID#, names, date started, salary etc) and it outputs in the "employeeTArea".

```
public class EmployeeView extends FrameView {
/** Define the ArrayList */
ArrayList <String> inventory = new ArrayList <String>();

public EmployeeView(SingleFrameApplication app) {

}// </editor-fold>

private void AddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    String c;
    String ID, firstName, lastName, annualSal, startDate;

    ID = IDField.getText();
    firstName = firstNameField.getText();
    lastName = lastNameField.getText();
    annualSal = annualSalField.getText();
    startDate = startDateField.getText();

    c = new String (ID);
    c = new String (firstName);
    c = new String (lastName);
    c = new String (annualSal);
    c = new String (startDate);
    inventory.add(c);
}

private void ListActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
```

The problem is here just below...though you may not see it everything after get(x) (firstName, lastName, ID etc etc) is underlined red. Just those words. Of course this creates a problem for after I store employee information in array by pressing the "addButton", I can no longer access that information when I press the "listButton" for it to display.

```
    String temp="";

    for (int x=0; x<=inventory.size()-1; x++) {
        temp = temp + inventory.get(x).ID + " "
                + inventory.get(x).firstName + " "
                + inventory.get(x).lastName + " "
                + inventory.get(x).annualSal + " "
                + inventory.get(x).startDate + "\n";
    }
    inventoryOut.setText(temp);

    class Company {
    String ID, firstName, lastName, annualSal, startDate, mileage;

    Company (String _ID, String _firstName,String _lastName, String _annualSal, String _startDate) {
        ID = _ID;
        firstName = _firstName;
        lastName = _lastName;
        annualSal = _annualSal;
        startDate = _startDate;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You sure set `c` to a lot of different things.

Comment: your `inventory` is an `ArrayList` of `String`s and as such it only holds `String`s and that class does not have `firstName`, `lastName` and others. I think you made a list of the wrong type. You might want a `List` of one of your own classes, one that contains those attributes.

Comment: I see you are declaring a `class Company` but don't see you using it anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

**Your problems**

Look at where you declare these variables. They are declared as `local`, when they need to be `global`. Declare them outside of any method declaration.

Also look at this declaration:

```
ArrayList <String> inventory = new ArrayList <String>();
```

You have parameterized `inventory` to type `String`, but you want to use it like it is of type `Employee`.

**Conventions**

The Java convention states that you should not be accessing members directly; you should be using `accessors` and `mutators`. For example:

```
public String getID()
{
    return ID;
}
```

**Some of your code**

```
c = new String (ID);
c = new String (firstName);
c = new String (lastName);
c = new String (annualSal);
c = new String (startDate);
inventory.add(c);
```

What you're doing here is declaring `c` as a new String, with the value in `ID`.. Then declaring it as a new `String` with the value of `firstName` etc etc. Essentially, you're only adding the `startDate` each time. Not to mention the fact that all of these values are already `String` objects.. There's really no benefit to creating new `String` objects from them.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList <String> inventory = new ArrayList <String>();` this is an ArrayList of String
so `inventory.get(x)` is a String

What you should put is `ArrayList <Employee> inventory = new ArrayList <Employee>();`

Comment: I had originally started with that actually, however then "Employee"  is underlined red.

Comment: Do you have a class called Employee ? If yes, you should import it

Comment: Ahhh, as i see in your code, the class name is actually "Company" not "Employee"